# Angular 5 - Get current time of video

Tags: html, angular

I have **HTML5** video in my component and want to get the current video time, while it is playing.

Here is what I've tried and it only gets the time once initially.

**Component TS:**

```
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @ViewChild('videoPlayer')
  private videoPlayer: ElementRef;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // only logs once
    console.log(this.videoPlayer.nativeElement.currentTime);
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    // only logs once
    console.log(this.videoPlayer.nativeElement.currentTime);
  }
}
```

**Component HTML:**

```
<video #videoPlayer [autoplay]="true" class="video">
    <source src="assets/videos/temp.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
      Browser not supported
</video>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can bind to the timeupdate event on the video tag set a variable to the value of the currentTime property of the video element.

**Component TS:**

```
export class RegisterComponent  {

  currentTime: number;

  setCurrentTime(data) {
     this.currentTime = data.target.currentTime;
  }
}
```

**Component HTML:**

```
<video [autoplay]="true" (timeupdate)="setCurrentTime($event)" class="video">
    <source src="assets/videos/temp.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
      Browser not supported
</video>
```

Answer (score 4):

**HTML**

```
<video [autoplay]="true" (timeupdate)="onTimeUpdate($event)" class="video">
    <source src="assets/videos/temp.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
      Browser not supported
</video>
```

**TS**

```
public onTimeUpdate(value){
    console.log(value.target.currentTime);
}
```